# Workers stuck in the seize operator

Tags: simulation, anylogic

In my model the seize operator seizes a workers agent which move a pallete from source to sink, this part is working fine.
But in the release operator I have configured the worker to go to their home node only if there is no more pallete, and the workers are going to the source node again directly from sink noode, but there they get stuck at the source node and not moving the pallete to sink node again.

Flow:
source -> seize -> moveToSink -> Release -> sink

Answer (score 0):

this should work properly the way you built it, however, its really difficult to know the reason for the problem from the info you provided. Maybe you can add screenshots showing the parameters you have chosen in your blocks. In all cases, make sure you have chosen the "Attach seized resources" in the seize block.